# Google play pepk.jar exporting private key error

Tags: java, google-play, android-app-signing

PEPK - Play Encrypt Private Key
pepk (Play Encrypt Private Key) is a tool for exporting private keys from a Java Keystore and encrypting them for transfer to Google Play as part of enrolling in App Signing by Google Play.

[image]

When i am run the command line, error occurred:

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=huoshanbox.jks --alias=huoshanbox --output=output.zip --include-cert --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem
    
Enter password for store 'huoshanbox.jks':
Enter password for key 'huoshanbox':
Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:563)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.encryptPrivateKeyWithCkmRsaAesKeyWrapEncryption(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:284)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:213)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:165)
```

This tool requires jdk 11+,i am tried JDK 11, JDK 17, JDK 20, but got the same error.
Which version of jdk should I use?

Comment: Resolved! using openjdk 11+ instead. https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads?page=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding' when trying to enroll to 'Let Google Play manage your app signing key'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76516045/cannot-find-any-provider-supporting-rsa-none-oaepwithsha1andmgf1padding-when-t)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved using openJDK 15 or higher.
But it remain to install openJDK. On openJdk website I find many openJDK versions but I do not find any installer tool.
As I am working with Windows, I find openJDK 17 on Microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/install
It can be installed with standard Windows installers (msi or winget). msi failed on my computer, but winget has installed openJDK 17 with success.