# 'Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding' when trying to enroll to 'Let Google Play manage your app signing key'

Tags: android, google-play, keystore

Hi I am trying to enroll to '**Let Google Play manage your app signing key**' but when I follow the steps I am getting this error :

[image: The output]

From what i have seen on other answers, Google used to give another parameter called `--encryptionkey` which is not given anymore, now the their tutorial look like this :

[image]

And I suspect the error to comme from the `--rsa-aes-encryption` parameter... but it's only a guess..

Here is a text version of the error to copy it more easily :

```
MacBook-Pro Desktop % java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=cbk.keystore --alias=release --output=cbk1 --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem
Enter password for store 'cbk.keystore':
Enter password for key 'release':
Error: Unable to export or encrypt the private key
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting RSA/NONE/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding
    at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:574)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.encryptPrivateKeyWithCkmRsaAesKeyWrapEncryption(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:284)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.run(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:213)
    at com.google.wireless.android.vending.developer.signing.tools.extern.export.ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.main(ExportEncryptedPrivateKeyTool.java:165)
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Hi, Any luck in generating the key? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Which Java version do you use? May be your Java version is too new. As a rule of thumb for Java never install non-LTS versions. Those versions are only for those who know what they are doing (more like public betas). So only use Java 8, 11 or 17 at the moment.

Comment: Any updates here? I'm still facing the same issue. Any lead will be very helpful.

Answer (score 24):

Use OpenJDK (https://jdk.java.net/) instead of the Oracle JDK; they are packaged with different tools, and evidently Google expects the OpenJDK set.

Answer (score 14):

You need to 2 things to solve this:

**1. Use Java JDK 21**

**2. Edit the private key path to also include the filename as `private_key.pem`**

I am on Mac and I resolved this following these steps:

1. Downloaded "ready for use jdk 21" from here https://jdk.java.net
2. Moved that to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` folder
3. Updated the profile with new `JAVA_HOME` path

```
nano ~/.zshenv

# ADD THIS AND SAVE
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home

source ~/.zshenv
```

4. Added the private key filename as well in the private key path.
5. My final command looks like this:

```
java -jar /Users/me/keys/Google-Play-Signing/pepk.jar --keystore=/Users/me/keys/app-release-key.keystore --alias=app --output=/Users/me/keys/Google-Play-Signing/app-key/app_private_key.pem --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=/Users/me/keys/Google-Play-Signing/encryption_public_key.pem
```

That's it.

Comment: Live saver! Worked for me on M1 Max Pro. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
This solution and the java version worked for me on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 13):

just download latest "ready for use jdk" from here https://jdk.java.net
and then:

use downloaded java.exe location like e:\download\jdk-20.0.2\bin\java.exe -jar pepk.jar --keystore=cbk.keystore --alias=release --output=cbk1 --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem

Comment: Remember to put `e:\download\jdk-20.0.2\bin\java.exe` in commas.

Answer (score 4):

I face this problem as well.

What you need to do is :

1. Download openjdk. In my case i use jdk11 version : https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads?field_java_parent_version_target_id=406&field_operating_system_target_id=All&field_architecture_target_id=All&field_java_package_target_id=All
2. Set your environment to the newly downloaded openjdkfolder.
3. `set JAVA_HOME="d:\openjdk11"`
4. `set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%`
5. put all required files like keysstore,pepk.jar and encryption_public_key.pem in one folder. follow this instruction from google console. change it according to your parameter : `java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=yourkeystore.keystore --alias=youralias --output=d:\newprivatekey --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=encryption_public_key.pem`

change `--output` to absolute path. In my my case, i will store the output key in my D: storage.

Answer (score 0):

This was very frustrating.  I **finally** got this to work following the descriptions above (openjdk-20) and adding a path **and filename with .pem extension** for the private key output.

```
java -jar C:\Users\Me\AndroidSafe\pepk.jar --keystore=C:\Users\Me\Documents\AndroidStuff\Bling\Bus\my_keystore.jks --alias=uploadkey --output=C:\Users\Me\AndroidSafe\output_private_key.pem --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=C:\Users\Me\AndroidSafe\encryption_public_key.pem
```

Other steps along the way included adding a bouncy castle jar (bcprov-jdk18on-176.jar) to
C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-20\lib
and adding the line
security.provider.14 = org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
to the C:\Program Files\Java\openjdk-20\conf\security\java.security file.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded latest OpenJDK and the above error was resolved!

(after first trying a couple of older Javas. Java can be really annoying)

"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21.0.1\bin\java" -jar ./pepk.jar --keystore=mykeystore.keystore --alias=myalias --output=encrypted_private_key_path --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=./encryption_public_key.pem